Terminal warning Sourcemap for xxx in node modules in svelte, vite, sentry
How do I stop this annoying warning in terminal?

Sourcemap for
"xxxxx/node_modules/@material/circular-progress/foundation.js" points
to missing source files

I tried the following
sentryVitePlugin({
        org: 'dogbase',
        project: 'dogbase-production',
        authToken: env.VITE_APP_SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
                //silent: true, // This will suppress all logs from the Sentry plugin
        errorHandler: (error) => {
          console.warn('Sentry Plugin Error:', error);
          // This will log the error as a warning but allow the build to continue
        },
        sourcemaps: {
          // Specify which build artifacts should be uploaded to Sentry
          assets: './dist/**',
          ignore: ['./node_modules/**'],
        },
      }),

